# Very slow method nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a back on nest.js and mysql db, when authorization request is very long because of the large user model and adjacent models, resulting in the client, I get an error that the request time is out. Can somebody please tell me how to fix it?

Client on next js

If i remove the attached models from the returned user model, the query will go faster, but i can't do it without them.

Comment: You can use ```Async/Await``` for asynchronous calling to the database and when it returns data then it will be fetched without any problems of timeout.

Comment: this is probably related to the db. you should put index on some of the columns to speed things up.